# The app Google Assistant - Dialogflow failed to show a table card

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a new issue when I add a table card like this, even static table, not dynamic

```
 app.intent('static table',(conv)=>{
      conv.ask(new Table({
          dividers : true,
          columns: ['alpha', 'beta', 'price'],
          rows: [
              [`1`, `2`, `3`],
          ],
      }));
  })

app.intent('dynamic table',(conv)=>{
      let row=[];
      var i;
      for (var i=0;i< conv.data.alpha.length;i++){
        row.push([conv.data.alpha[i],`${conv.data.beta[i]}- ${conv.data.beta2[i]}`,`Rp.${conv.data.pricemin[i]}-${conv.data.pricemax[i]}`])
      }
      console.log(row);
      conv.ask(new Table({
          dividers : true,
          columns: ['alpha', 'beta', 'price'],
          rows: row,
      }));
  })
```

[[screenshot]the app is error, but the response debug still give a table card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt2Mw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, **Table Cards** are not interactable, if you only show the table, it leaves the conversation because the table never expect anything from user.

Try adding another response once the table response is sent like below one. This will hold the conversation and keep it going. Simply the ball will be in user court.

```
app.intent('static table',(conv)=>{
      conv.ask('Here is table details'); // edit this is required
      conv.ask(new Table({
          dividers : true,
          columns: ['alpha', 'beta', 'price'],
          rows: [
              [`1`, `2`, `3`],
          ],
      }));
     conv.ask('Which response would you like to see next?'); // this is missing
  })
```

Comment: thank you 
but still didn't response.
the system will be response when conv.ask(`conversation response`) before the table card

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the 1st one. Editing the answer for the future.